# Hacer varias consultas axios con for loop

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, bucles, axios

Estoy realizando peticiones con axios en un loop para la paginación y me devuelve múltiples resultados, la cuestión es cuando no tenga más resultados cambiar la categoría y hacer de nuevo la petición.

Este es el código hasta el momento:

```js
let pagina=0,valor=0;
const categoria = ["Criterios", "Renombres"];
async function oConsulta(){
    const eResultado = []
    for(let i = 0; i < pages;i++) {
        console.log(`PÁGINA = ${i}`)
        const cObtener = await axios.get(`https://...com/?pagina=${pagina}&categoria=${categoria[valor]}`)
        eResultado.push(cObtener.data.cuentas.map(n => n.cuenta.nombre))
        if(cObtener.data.cuentas.map(n => n.cuenta.nombre).length > 0){
          console.log(`${pagina}`)
          pagina = pagina + 100;
        } 
    }
});
    return console.log(eResultado);
}

oConsulta();
```

La intención es cuando no obtenga más resultados cambiar la categoría y hacer la peticion y obtener los resultados junto a la primera consulta.

```js
            if(cObtener.data.cuentas.map(n => n.cuenta.nombre).length > 0){
              console.log(`${pagina}`)
              pagina = pagina + 100;
            } else valor = valor+1; oConsulta(); // Aumento el valor así cambio la categoria y vuelvo a llamar a la funcion.
```

Pero no logro cumplir con su cometido, otra forma que he pensado sería hacer múltiples con axios.all después unir los datos, aunque entiendo que de esta manera también se debe poder así no repetir más código.

Comment: No suena nada eficiente lo que intentas hacer. Desde el lado servidor parece un ataque al recibir tantas solicitudes en tan poco tiempo desde el mismo cliente. Por otro lado, ¿Qué sentido tiene pedir consultas paginadas para luego unir todas las respuestas? ¿Acaso el servidor sólo acepta consultas paginadas?  Podrías obtener todos los resultados de cada cada categoría y luego trabajar con los mismos. Sería sólo 1 petición por categoría. El filtrado lo harías sobre todo el conjunto de datos. Sin embargo, sigue siendo poco eficiente. ¿No puedes aplicar ese filtro en el servidor?

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras, se me paso el detalle de mencionar que estoy trabajando con una api la cual me devuelve array con la información y tiene una paginación de ahí el recorrido por paginación. La cuestión es cuando no tiene más datos revise las otras categorías.

Comment: En cuanto a unir todas las respuesta me refiero a poder trabajar con ellas como me devuelve la primera consulta en eResultado y es la única forma de hacerlo al ser un api sin tener que repetir más el código la opción más viable.

Comment: Entiendo, pero si la API responde a una *query string* para el paginado, es muy extraño que no responda sin la variable del mismo. Algo como: `https://la_api.com/?categoria=la_categoria`. Eso, si la API está bien implementada, debería devolver *todos* los registros para esa categoría. Aunque claro está que tal vez devuelva muchos datos o sólo devuelva un grupo de los mismos. En todo caso, sólo la documentación de la API que estás consumiendo te puede aclarar este asunto. Saludos

Comment: Por otra parte, esa reasignación a la variable `pagina` que haces dentro del bucle, no tiene mucho sentido, la verdad no entiendo muy bien lo que pretendes lograr con eso. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras así es como mencionas la api filtra por la categoría y la paginación indiferentemente de la posición, la paginación  dentro del bucle es para que vaya alternando la paginación ya que por cada pagina devuelve 100 resultados y en caso de existir más alterna paginación y obtiene más resultados. La cuestión es que la consulta la realiza bien, lo que estoy intentando hacer es cambiar la categoría cuando no hay más resultados... Pero creo que no va a ser posible o no veo la forma de hacerlo, ahora mismo lo que hice es  crear otro consulta cObtener2 y realizar la consulta.

Comment: Realizar la consulta con el mismo loop, pero pensé que habría alguna forma más eficiente de hacerlo y es lo que estoy intentando.